# Javascript Date() returns wrong weekday for certain dates

Tags: javascript

After getting that issue with the wrong weekday for dates from Sep 1, 2017 and later, I found that changing the sequence of 1 statemtent (setDate) returns correct results. See code below. When I enter 1.9.17 (which is Sep 1, 2017) I get Sunday, with the changed code it's Friday. Can somebody explain that to me? Issue occurs in FF, Chrome and Edge.

```
<body>
<input type="text" onchange="wday(this.value);">
<script>
function wday() {
  var x = wday.arguments[0].split(".");
  if (x[2].length<4) x[2] += 2000;
  var y = new Date();
  y.setFullYear(x[2]);
  y.setMonth(x[1]-1);
  y.setDate(x[0]);
  var z = new Array("So","Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa");
  alert("wrong "+z[y.getDay()])
  wday2(wday.arguments)
  }
function wday2() {
  var x = wday.arguments[0].split(".");
  if (x[2].length<4) x[2] += 2000;
  var y = new Date();
  y.setDate(x[0]);
  y.setMonth(x[1]-1);
  y.setFullYear(x[2]);
  var z = new Array("So","Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa");
  alert("correct "+z[y.getDay()])
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should log `y` to see what date it's creating

Comment: And I would bet the year is incorrect, as `17` is'nt really a valid input for `setFullYear`, or at least it won't set the year to 2017

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/00mpwz97/

Comment: The code was incorrect: if (x[2].length<4) x[2] += 2000; should be: if (x[2].length<4) x[2] = 2000+parseInt(x[2]); Also with that correction I get "Sun Oct 01 2017 22:34:16 GMT+0200". I even tried  setFullYear(2017), setMonth(8) and setDate(1), same error.

Answer (score 2):

`setMonth` can set the month to one where the current date (today is the 31st; September has 30 days) doesn’t exist. The overflow is turned into the appropriate day in the following month.

```
> var d = new Date();
> d
Wed Aug 31 2016 13:30:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
> d.setMonth(8); // September
> d
Sat Oct 01 2016 13:30:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Construct dates all at once to avoid this sort of problem entirely. Your year-adjusting code is also broken (it’ll concatenate `2000` instead of adding it), and referencing arguments using `func.arguments` is really bad practice.

```
var WEEKDAYS = ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"];

function wday(dateString) {
    var parts = dateString.split('.');
    var year = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
    var month = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
    var day = parseInt(parts[0], 10);

    if (parts[2].length < 4) {
        year += 2000;
    }

    var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);

    return WEEKDAYS[date.getDay()];
}
```

Use more functions for bonus points.

```
const WEEKDAYS = ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"];

function parseYear(yearString) {
    const year = parseInt(yearString, 10);

    return yearString.length < 4 ?
        year + 2000 :
        year;
}

function parseDottedDate(dateString) {
    const [day, month, year] = dateString.split('.');

    return new Date(
        parseYear(year),
        parseInt(month, 10) - 1,
        parseInt(day, 10)
    );
}

function wday(dateString) {
    const date = parseDottedDate(dateString);

    return WEEKDAYS[date.getDay()];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - your code works perfect. And I apologise for the confusion with the +2000. But I still don't understand why I get the same error when using the explicit numbers: 
    var y = new Date();
    y.setFullYear(2017);
    y.setMonth(8);
    y.setDate(1);
returns Sunday instead of Friday

Comment: @Fritz: Whether they come from variables or literals, the behaviour is the same. `new Date()` takes the current date, which is August 31st, 2016. `setFullYear` sets the year to 2017, making the date August 31st, 2017. `setMonth` sets the month to September, making the date September 31st, 2017, but there is no September 31st, so it becomes October 1st. Finally, `setDate` sets the date to the 1st, but it was already the 1st.

Comment: That's it: I was not aware of new Date() having the current date as initial value. I usually rely on the german website wiki.selfhtml.org. They don't mention that initial date.
Thanks again - you made my day.